# What is ~/.local folder in Mac OS used for?

Tags: macos

As title. I'm a (Neo)Vim user and today I noticed that some of the neovim files are stored in `~/.local/share/nvim/`, and it is the only folder inside it. Now I'm considering putting some of the log files under the `~/.local/share/`. the folder is named "share" so I'm also wondering whether it would indeed imply that the folder would be shared?

Comment: That's not a path defined by Apple. It was probably chosen by whoever created the nvim installer you used. The name suggests that it's stuff that would go in `/usr/local` in a traditional Unix filesystem layout, but the nvim installer puts it in `~/.local` when you don't have admin privs to modify the system-wide `/usr/local` when you install nvim.

Comment: @Spiff - user cannot modify the boot drive since Big Sur, so old-style nix mappings no longer work. Writable alternative locations must be used & I'd guess this is a 'good enough' equivalent.

Comment: @Tetsujin `/usr/local` is still writable with admin privs: `sudo touch /usr/local/SpiffWasHere && ls -l /usr/local/`. macOS sets up something like filesystem overlays for some of these locations. But if you don't have admin privs and still want to install a piece of FOSS for your own account, it makes sense that they find paths within your home directory to put stuff that normally would have been installed in system-wide locations.

Comment: @Spiff: Thanks for your explanation! I think your comment deserves some upvotes and if you have time you can organize it into an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This folder is often found on Linux. It is part of the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). Another related folder is `~/.config`.

`~/.local/share` is for "user-specific data files". The related `/usr/share` folder is "for all read-only architecture independent data files" in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s11.html).

See also [this Ask Ubuntu question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14535/whats-the-local-folder-for-in-my-home-directory).

Answer (score 2):

It contains shared resources, not files which can be shared with other users. [I'm not quite sure exactly what they're shared with, but Wine uses the same structure]

You can confirm this just using Finder set to show invisibles  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>.</kbd>  & getting Info on the folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's not a path defined by Apple. It was probably chosen by whoever created the `nvim` installer you used. The name suggests that it's stuff that would go in `/usr/local` in a traditional Unix filesystem layout, but the `nvim` installer puts it in `~/.local` when you don't have admin privileges to modify the system-wide `/usr/local` when you install `nvim`.